# Python 3.7. Tengo problema para solucionar un error . AttributeError: 'Moto' object has no attribute 'estado'

Tags: python

```
# Ejercicio de Herencia
class Vehiculos():

    def __init__(self, marca, modelo):

        self.marca = marca
        self.modelo = modelo
        self.enmarcha = False
        self.acelera = False
        self.frena = False


def arrancar(self):
    self.enmarcha=True

def acelera(self):
    self.acelera = True

def frena(self):
    self.frena = True

def estado(self):
    print("Marca: ", self.marca, "\nModelo: ", self.modelo, "\nEn Marcha: ",
        self.enmarcha, "\nAcelarado: ", self.acelera, "\nFrenado: ", self.frena)



class Moto(Vehiculos):
    pass

miMoto = Moto("Honda", "CRB")

miMoto.estado()
/// la llamada al objeto miMoto debe imprimir el string del método def estado(self): , pero me da error AttributeError: 'Moto' object has no attribute 'estado'///
```

Answer (score 1):

> Al parecer el problema era la identación, no habias situado las demas
>   funciones dentro de la clase `Vehiculos`, prueba esto:

```
class Vehiculos():

    def __init__(self, marca, modelo):
        self.marca = marca
        self.modelo = modelo
        self.enmarcha = False
        self.acelera = False
        self.frena = False


    def arrancar(self):
        self.enmarcha=True

    def acelera(self):
        self.acelera = True

    def frena(self):
        self.frena = True

    def estado(self):
        print("Marca: ", self.marca, "\nModelo: ", self.modelo, "\nEn Marcha: ",
        self.enmarcha, "\nAcelarado: ", self.acelera, "\nFrenado: ", self.frena)



class Moto(Vehiculos):
    pass


miMoto =  Moto("Honda", "CRB")

miMoto.estado()
```